# Orgmode priorities: possible more than A B C?

Tags: emacs, org-mode

Is it possible to have more than 3 priority statuses in Orgmode?
I'd like to have A B C and D.
Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has been working for me with priorities ranging from `A` to `J`:

```lisp
(setq org-enable-priority-commands t
      org-highest-priority ?A
      org-default-priority ?J
      org-lowest-priority ?J)
```

However, I nearly never make use of `F`, `G`, `H`, `I`, `J` ...
At the time being I use org `9.3.4`.
It seems to work without the first line `org-enable-priority-commands t` as well.

So you could write:

```lisp
(setq org-highest-priority ?A
      org-default-priority ?B
      org-lowest-priority ?D)
```

Comment: Yes, it does work, thanks. I realized that for some reason in some manuals I find the variable org-priority-highest while in others org-highest-priority, and in my latest Emacs only the later works. For instance, @Juancho referred to org-priority-highest, which would not work in my case.

Comment: Both of them should work in recent Emacs (correction: the version of Org mode that is distributed with emacs does not seem to have these aliases): `org-highest-priority` is aliased to `org-priority-highest`. But there was a bug that was fixed on 2020-03-10 with these aliases (commit ID 097b4e6ca0d9265710a61f41d4a332eeb20a2e40).

Answer (score 2):

You can change the number of priorities by customizing `org-priority-highest` and `org-priority-lowest`, and there is also `org-priority-default`.

Or you can set it on a per-file basis.

Check for more options in the [documentation](https://orgmode.org/manual/Priorities.html#Priorities).

Comment: Thanks, for some reason when I set (setq org-priority-highest ?A)
(setq org-priority-lowest ?D), nothing happens. I can only go from A to C.

Comment: Actually, org-priority-highest does not work, but org-highest-priority works. I suppose there is an error in the documentation?

Comment: No: the two are aliased together, although there was a bug with the aliases. But the version of Org mode that is distributed with emacs does not seem to have these aliases.

Comment: The aliases went into version 9.3.3 of Org mode. The version that is distributed with current emacs 28.0.50 seems to be 9.3.